# finding values between given inputs using sql

Tags: mysql

Am just curious is there a way to extract specific elements from database in a specified range based on 2 inputs. 
ex: SELECT books WHERE MINIMUM price = 10 AND MAXIMUM price = 35, using mysql?

Comment: Sure it is. Can you please provide your table definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SELECT` to find rows with values in certain ranges. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE price >= 10 AND price <= 20;
```

or you may use `BETWEEN` instead:

```
SELECT * FROM books
 WHERE price BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```

Both queries above will return all rows with price between 10 and 20.